# Salesforce Surveys Background Image Deployment

Tags: salesforce-survey

I have a question on Salesforce Surveys.
I created a Survey in a Sandbox org that has a background image specified. I wanted to deploy the same into another Sandbox org.

I understand that we can use the  tag to deploy Surveys, however the background image does not get deployed. Is there a way to deploy the Background image alongwith the Survey together?

Or do we need to first deploy the Survey to the target sandbox and then manually edit the same to specify the background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use package(manage/unmanaged) to deploy the survey from Source to Target Org, which would pull all the dependencies, and hence you will get the background image as well.

Else if you are using metadata to deploy, you can create a new Version and edit and change the background image, as dependencies are not pulled.

Either you can add dependencies in package.xml or manually change it in a new version in target Org.

Note- Not only background Image, font, color, etc which you have edited through the branding tab in Survey builder are stored in the branding table and need to be pulled separately(except in packages) and would be missing in the target Org.

Comment: Can you pls show sample package.xml to deploy survey from one org to other.

Answer (score 2):

The background image (and logo image) consist of metadata types BrandingSet and ContentAsset. The survey is a Flow - the branding set is referenced in there. So to make a complete deployment you need to add the Flow, BrandingSet and the ContentAssets referenced in the BrandingSet.

One thing to note is that a new branding set seems to be created for each new version of the survey, so make sure you pick the right one.

Comment: Note that the `backgroundImageUrl` is also a `ContentAsset` with a system-assigned name like `X0LwDJ000000CgMm0AK72403209_135c_464`